# Property does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

estoy practicando con laravel pero tengo algunas dudas, quiero aplicar un middleware que le prohiba el acceso a una ruta si un usuario logueado tiene "0" en la columna "wizard" de mi tabla "empresas" y lo redireccione a completar su proceso pero si este tiene "1" en el campo lo deje pasar a la ruta /dashboard

declare mi modelo de la siguiente forma:

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Empresa extends Model
    {
        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'empresas';

        /**
        * The database primary key value.
        *
        * @var string
        */
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        /**
         * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = ['nombreempresa',
        'nombrecomercial',
        'idfiscal',
        'logo',
        'adminid',
        'tel',
        'pais',
        'status',
        'email',
        'acceso',
        'verified',
        'categoria',
        'sector',
        'tipo',
        'serial',
        'wizard',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'];
        public function user()
          {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
          }
    }
```

El codigo del middleware es:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;
use App\Empresa;

class WizardVerification
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
         if(Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)->wizard && !Auth::check()){
            return redirect('/dashboard');
          }
         return $next($request);
       }
}
```

en mis rutas lo llame asi:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['wizard']], function () {

/*Todas las rutas que esten en este grupo estaran restringidas si el usuario no completo su informacion y se restringira su paso si la no se encuentra logueado.*/
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
});
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

pero al hacer la prueba me aparece el error "propety [wizard] does not exist" que estoy haciendo mal? porque segui cuidadosamente [este tutorial](https://www.nigmacode.com/laravel/Crear-middleware-en-Laravel) pero no lo logre hacer funcionar, espero alguien pueda explicarme porque esta mal mi codigo, saludos!!!

Comment: Además de lo que te dice @Shassain, tenés mal armado el condicional. Estás diciendo `si tiene wizard y no está logueado`. Si no está logueado, `Auth::user()->id` te va a tirar un error, así que primero deberías chequear eso. Y si tiene wizard no puede estar *no logueado*, con lo cual el condicional no se va a cumplir nunca. En todo caso entiendo que querés decir `si no está logueado O no tiene wizard`. Por otro lado, estás haciendo un redirect si se cumple la condición, con lo cual TODAS las URLs van a terminar en `/dashboard`. Me parece que tenés todo mezclado.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando tu haces:

```
Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)
```

Obtienes una objeto `Builder`, el cual aun no pertence a un modelo Empresa, por lo tanto no puedes acceder a la propiedad wizard.

Pero si haces:

```
Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

En este caso ya obtienes un collection de Empresa(osea un array con objetos empresa). Aun así tu tendrías que indicar la posición del objeto al cual deseas acceder, esto seria asi: `Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)->get()[0]->wizard` (seria una solucion).

Pero yo tomaría otra opción:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  $data=Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)->first();// obtengo solo un registro el cual es un objeto, entonces ahora puedo hacer
  if($data->wizard && !Auth::check()){
     return redirect('/dashboard');
  }
  return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: hice la modificacion pero me arroja el error "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: @Abdiel Hernadez eso sucede porque tu usuario no esta logueado.